# At what traffic point is it worth it to start looking to put ads on a website?

Tags: google-adsense, advertising, traffic, monetize

My Google Analytics have slowly been climbing over time and I'm wondering how many unique visitors I need to make it worth my time to look into monetizing that traffic with advertising on the site?  Thanks.

Comment: I think this question is too subjective

Comment: I started around 1,000 page views a week. You need a user base in order to gain some profit from ads.

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa why have you not put in a close request? Mine seems to be the only one

Comment: Nick the reason were suggesting to close it is because there's too many variables and not one answer is going to be correct. If my website was very specific to a niche category and I had 10 people a day I would place ad's on it. It does not take much time to put AdSense on your website but you're not likely going to make much unless you have thousands of visitors.

Comment: @Anagio Simply because I've not the reputation to vote to close a question. I can only flag it and that's exactly what I've done.

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa didn't know you didn't have that option

Comment: should I rephrase it to something like, about how many unique visitors a day would I need to make $100 a day off advertising?

Comment: @nick2653 - That would still be an extremely subjective question. For example, many people that have delved into making money with Adsense etc will know that the insurance and legal niches are highly lucrative. It may only take 10 visitors to make $100 if your site is related to a niche where a lot of money is involved... Whereas if your website specializes in dishwasher tablets, you will probably need substantially more visitors. There is no golden number.

Answer (score -1):

In my experience, as soon as you hit 100 visitors/day, you can make enough from basic Google Adsense to cover your costs (assuming you are on cheaper hosting when you have fewer visitors).

In terms of time, Adsense takes only a few minutes of actual implementation (not counting the few days waiting to be approved). Even solutions such as BuySellAds, intended for high-trafficked sites, don't take too long to set up.

So I would suggest setting up Google Adsense, try a few ad positions and see how you do.